# How to copy a range in excel and then resize and paste in word with a macro

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, resize, export-to-word

```
Sub CopyToWord()

    Dim objWord As New Word.Application


    'copying the range that I want to paste in Word
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("grid_copy")
        .Range("b1:AA42").CopyPicture xlScreen

    End With

    'pasting the picture in a new Word document
    With objWord
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 651
        .Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 500
        'Those two lines don't work to resize the picture that i'm pasting in word
        .Visible = True
    End With


End Sub
```

The code is actualy working but I'm not capable of applying the resize of the image that I want. Do you guys know a way that I can resize the picture that i'm pasting in Word coming form a range in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub CopyToWord()
'copying the range that I want to paste in Word
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("grid_copy").Range("b1:AA42").CopyPicture xlScreen
'pasting the picture in a new Word document
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document, wdImg As Word.InlineShape
With wdApp
  .Visible = True
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Add
  With wdDoc
    .Range.Paste
    Set wdImg = .InlineShapes(1)
    With wdImg
      .Height = 651
      .Width = 500
    End With
  End With
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think we are very close! but I got an error "function or variable expected" on this line "Set wdImg = .Range.Paste" pointing at .Paste... Would you happen to know why?

Comment: Not sure what happened there. Try the revised code.