# VBScript: Resize Picture in Word from Excel

Tags: excel, image, ms-word, vbscript

I copy a Range of Cells from Excel as a Picture and move it to Word.
I would like to Resize the Picture, but I don't have a clue, how I can use the copied Picture to resize. Here my last attempt:

```
Set ObjWkBk = ObjXl.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xlsx")

Set ObjWd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set ObjDoc = ObjWd.Documents.Add("C:\test.docx")

ObjWkBk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").CopyPicture

Set bp = ObjDoc.Bookmarks("Ending").Range

bp.Paste

'My attempt to resize
With ObjDoc
   .Height = 2000
   .Width = 2000
End With
'attempt end


ObjDoc.SaveAs ("C:\test1.docx")

ObjDoc.Close: ObjWd.Quit: ObjWkBk.Close: ObjXl.Quit
Set ObjDoc = Nothing: Set ObjWd = Nothing: Set ObjWkBk = Nothing: Set ObjXl = Nothing
```

I don't have a clue how to catch the actual picture and resize it.

Comment: You’re attempting to resize the document not the picture?

Comment: Yeah, but I would like to resize the picture. I don't know how to address the picture.

Comment: Take a look at the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/word), especially the [`InlineShapes` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.inlineshapes) of the [`Range` object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range). [This may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61880312/692942) but you'll need to re-purpose to use with VBScript.

Comment: @user692942 great and thanks a lot, that solved my problem! I normally only check VBScript Questions, but that VBA Topic helped me.